# mysql login in problems

Tags: mysql, installation, vps

I have had this issue multiple times on different VPSs I have. I usually find different ways around them but I want to solve this problem permanently.

I get these errors when I try to log into mysql:

```
(env) lit@digitalocean:~/HowLit/init$ mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'lit'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
(env) lit@digitalocean:~/HowLit/init$ mysql -u lit
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'lit'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

then if I try with root:

```
(env) lit@digitalocean:~/HowLit/init$ mysql -u root
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

however if I do:

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

and then enter my normal password for user *lit* then it works.

However I cannot create a database nor anything else. 
I've purged and reinstalled mysql multiple times and run into the same errors over and over.

What causes these errors? What am I doing wrong in my installation?

```
mysql> show grants;
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Access+denied+for+user+%27root%40localhost%27+%28using+password%3A+YES%29

Comment: Crafted my question sort badly. My real question is why does this happen every time I install mysql? What am I doing wrong with my installation?

Comment: `mysql` doesn't prompt for password by default. you have explicitly tell it to do so `mysql -u root -p`

Comment: that I understand. but now I just completely removed mysql, purged, autoclean and autoremove. then when i did a reinstall it finally prompted me a root password from the start. now i can do `mysql -u root -p` with no problems and without doing all the grant stuff. Going to do more research on why this happens. Too many times has this been asked how to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try logging in with this command:
`mysql -u root -p`

or

`mysql -u <your user name> -p`

Enter the password you set earlier for those users.

If you neglect to add the -p, mysql will assume you are trying to log in without a password, and if that doesn't match the password stored in the mysql user table, it will reject your attempt to log in.

Once you are logged in, enter: `show grants;`

Now that you've shown the user grants, the issue is that the root user is set up in a way that will require you to use sudo.  To fix this log in as you have with sudo, and then run the following lines.

Please do this carefully.  After making sure you have backups of any mysql data you need (this will not delete your data, but it’s always good to play it safe), first run:
`DROP USER 'root'@'localhost';`

Then immediately run, without logging out first:
`CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '<<<YOUR DESIRED PASSWORD>>>'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

You should now be able to log in without sudo.  For non digitalocean machines, I would prefer to limit the root db account to localhost for optimum security, but if you select a sufficient password, you should be fine either way.

**If you don't want to create the user above, you can also try logging in using:**
`mysql -u root -h localhost -p`
or 
`mysql -u lit -h localhost -p` (if you created a user lit@localhost in mysql)

**Since you sound interested in debugging the root cause** (bravo), you can run this and see what other users have been created in mysql.  Log into mysql, and then run:
`use mysql; select * from user;`

Pasting the output into a text editor with word wrap disabled will make it readable.

You should see what other user accounts have been created.  Keep in mind some accounts may take priority over your account's privileges, and that may be causing your login issues.  I wouldn't recommend posting the output online even though the passwords are hashed out.  Good luck.

Comment: added the show grants output. `mysql -u root -p` will only work if i do `sudo` before it. Why must this happen with every mysql install? Am I doing something wrong during installation?

Comment: hi Kyle, thanks for showing the grants, I added four more paragraphs at the end that should fix your sudo issue.

Comment: could you explain the '%' change and also what I am doing in my installation for this to happen?

Comment: Certainly: the % makes your user have permission to connect over all IPs, not just localhost.  As for your installation, it's difficult to know how you set up mysql without seeing the installation steps.  It's generally safer to limit the user to locahost if possible, but if you select a sufficient password it should be fine either way, and your firewall will usually also prevent outside connections by default.